# Dice game not working with multiple players

Tags: python, dice

I am trying to create a game where you choose how many players there will be, name those players, and then one player is chosen at random.

From there, that chosen player would pick a number in between 1 and 10 that they DON'T want to land on.

Then, the dice rolls and if they land on that number, everyone else gets to pick a dare for him/her. If it doesn't, the game just randomly picks another player and the process begins again.

**The problem is though, the program doesn't get past the part where it asks you which number you don't want to land on**. This is weird, as it works fine with one person.

Here is the full code, you are looking for line 23:

```
# Pass Or Dare

from random import randint
firsttry = True
def playerpicked(list):
    listwords = len(list)
    numpicked = randint(0, listwords - 1)
    userpicked = list[numpicked]
    return userpicked

while firsttry:
    try:
        playercount = int(input('How many players will there be?\n'))
    except ValueError:
        print("That isn't a number. Please enter a number without decimals.")
    else:
        firsttry = False
        playernames = [input("Name of Player {}: ".format(i)) for i in range(1, playercount + 1)]
        while True:
            playerturn = playerpicked(playernames)
            print("The Player picked is:",playerturn)
            while True:
                try:
                    darenum = int(input(playerturn + ", which number do you NOT want to land on?\n"))
                except ValueError:
                    print("Please enter a number.")
                else:
                    if darenum > 10 or darenum < 1:
                        print("Please enter a number between 1 and 10.\n")
                    else:
                        break
                    print("Okay. Rolling the dice...")
                    numpick = randint(1, 10)
                    print("The number chosen is " + str(numpick) + ".")
                    if numpick == darenum:
                        print("Whoops! The number you chose was the one that we landed on! Everyone agree on a dare for " + playerturn + "!\n\n")
                        input("Press Enter once " + playerturn + " has done a dare...\n")
                    else:
                        print(playerturn + " has escaped! Moving on to the next person.\n\n")
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your original code, with errors sinalization (read the code's comments):

```
# Pass Or Dare

from random import randint
firsttry = True
def playerpicked(list):
    listwords = len(list)
    numpicked = randint(0, listwords - 1)
    userpicked = list[numpicked]
    return userpicked

while firsttry:
    try:
        playercount = int(input('How many players will there be?\n'))
    except ValueError:
        print("That isn't a number. Please enter a number without decimals.")
    else:
        firsttry = False
        playernames = [input("Name of Player {}: ".format(i)) for i in range(1, playercount + 1)]
        while True:
            playerturn = playerpicked(playernames)
            print("The Player picked is:",playerturn)
            while True:
                try:
                    darenum = int(input(playerturn + ", which number do you NOT want to land on?\n"))
                except ValueError:
                    print("Please enter a number.")
                else: #there is no if for this else
                    if darenum > 10 or darenum < 1:
                        print("Please enter a number between 1 and 10.\n")
                    else:
                        break #this break would break the while True above
                    print("Okay. Rolling the dice...")
                    numpick = randint(1, 10)
                    print("The number chosen is " + str(numpick) + ".")
                    if numpick == darenum:
                        print("Whoops! The number you chose was the one that we landed on! Everyone agree on a dare for " + playerturn + "!\n\n")
                        input("Press Enter once " + playerturn + " has done a dare...\n")
                    else:
                        print(playerturn + " has escaped! Moving on to the next person.\n\n") 
                        #there should be a break in here, otherwise the function would be stuck in the second while True
```

The fixed code, changing what I mentioned in the comments above:

```
# Pass Or Dare

from random import randint
firsttry = True
def playerpicked(list):
    listwords = len(list)
    numpicked = randint(0, listwords - 1)
    userpicked = list[numpicked]
    return userpicked

while firsttry:
    try:
        playercount = int(input('How many players will there be?\n'))
    except ValueError:
        print("That isn't a number. Please enter a number without decimals.")
    else:
        firsttry = False
        playernames = [input("Name of Player {}: ".format(i)) for i in range(1, playercount + 1)]
        while True:
            playerturn = playerpicked(playernames)
            print("The Player picked is:",playerturn)
            while True:
                try:
                    darenum = int(input(playerturn + ", which number do you NOT want to land on?\n"))
                except ValueError:
                    print("Please enter a number.")

                if darenum > 10 or darenum < 1:
                    print("Please enter a number between 1 and 10.\n")

                else:

                    print("Okay. Rolling the dice...")
                    numpick = randint(1, 10)
                    print("The number chosen is " + str(numpick) + ".")

                    if numpick == darenum:
                        print("Whoops! The number you chose was the one that we landed on! Everyone agree on a dare for " + playerturn + "!\n\n")
                        input("Press Enter once " + playerturn + " has done a dare...\n")

                    else:
                        print(playerturn + " has escaped! Moving on to the next person.\n\n")
                        break
```

Comment: Just improved the answer with more details. See the first code's comments and then check the second one. It was mainly `if`, `else` and `break` being wrongly applied

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fast review of the algorithm, the problem was that the break you used while checking if the darenumber was between the desired range, causing to loop back again and never getting out of there.
Also, it's recommended that you check your control structure because it´s what made the problem.
Lastly, I strongly recommend an exit feature of your game because in some point in has to end. Hope it helps:

```
from random import randint

def playerpicked(list):
    listwords = len(list)
    numpicked = randint(0, listwords - 1)
    userpicked = list[numpicked]
    return userpicked

playercount = 0
while playercount < 1:
    try:
        playercount = int(input('How many players will there be?\n'))
    except ValueError:
        print("That isn't a number. Please enter a number without decimals.")

playernames = [input("Name of Player {}: ".format(i)) for i in range(1, playercount + 1)]
print("Press 0 while it's your turn to finish the game")
while True:
    playerturn = playerpicked(playernames)
    print("The Player picked is:",playerturn)
    darenum = -1
    while (darenum > 10 or darenum < 0):
        try:
            darenum = int(input(playerturn + ", which number do you NOT want to land on?\n"))
            if darenum > 10 or darenum < 1:
                print("Please enter a number between 1 and 10.\n")
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number.")
    if darenum == 0:
        break
    print("Okay. Rolling the dice...")
    numpick = randint(1, 10)
    print("The number chosen is " + str(numpick) + ".")
    if numpick == darenum:
        print("Whoops! The number you chose was the one that we landed on! Everyone agree on a dare for " + playerturn + "!\n\n")
        input("Press Enter once " + playerturn + " has done a dare...\n")
    else:
        print(playerturn + " has escaped! Moving on to the next person.\n\n") 

print("Game Over")
```